# My Philips Meridian 191EL2 LED monitor's brightness resets to 90 on power up

Tags: display, brightness, led

It is the inbuilt monitor menu. It just doesn't save what I set. How can I control the brightness from OS. I am on windows 7.

nvidia xfx 9500gt graphics card installed.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, set the `ICC` profile to **sRGB Color Space Profile** 
(Just in case of any custom `ICC` profile affects `DDC/CI`, this avoids it.)

Second, **reset** your Philips!:

> Menu -> Setup -> Reset -> (Yes)

If you see the brightness goes to 100 after reset, then you're in luck, go ahead and set a lower brightness =]